# Determinant division by arithmetic formula

Tags: arithmetic, determinant

I am trying to solve this problem with no luck.
I am supposed to prove that the determinant detA:

[detA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIBOY.png)

is divisible by the arithmetic formula:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUjY9.png)

I've tried separating the determinant by using the characteristic I know regarding determinants, especially trying to write the determinant as a sum of the coefficients in the last row (each determinant in the sum has only one coefficient in the last row that is not equal 0), but I haven't been able to prove the statement with this method.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Add all the lines to the last one, meaning: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i\to C_n$$ which is a valid linear transformation.